# How to prove that these limits exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have encountered two limits that I cannot manipulate into sensible $\varepsilon-\delta$ proofs:

1. $\lim\limits_{x,y \to 0,0} \frac{(x-y)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$
2. $\lim\limits_{x,y \to 0,0} \frac{1-\cos(xy)}{y^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**:

1) Note that $0 \le (x-y)^2 \le 2(x^2+y^2)$. Then squeeze.

2) Note that $0 \le 1-\cos(xy) \le \dfrac{1}{2}(xy)^2$. Then squeeze.

If you do need to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for the limits and you are not allowed to use anything else, then you can still use the above inequalities to make finding a suitable $\delta > 0$ easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've skipped directly to epsilon-delta without thinking about the squeeze theorem